# How to check if there is an existing MongoDB connection using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have an express app that connects to MongoDB via mongoose, and I also have an init script that will occasionally connect to MongoDB.

Is there any way to detect if there is an existing connection to the DB, so I will not need to connect again in the script anytime I want to run it, also is there any consequences for connecting to the DB multiple times via mongoose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can check this using `mongoose.connection.readyState`,

ex.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
console.log(mongoose.connection.readyState);
```

The  state would return **1** if already connected.

Answer (score 3):

You can check the `readyState`

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
console.log(mongoose.connection.readyState);
```